# geometry nodes, why are the points locked in the (0,0,0) position?

Tags: geometry-nodes

[image]

[image]

As you can see in the images, the points are not in the same position as the mesh

Comment: Hello, could be a couple of things.. please share your file on https://blend-exchange.com/, pasting the provided  link into your post